# I got this shape (1,254,254,1) while expected shape is (1,254,254,3)

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, image-preprocessing

Image comes from the front end in PIL I preprocess it but it giving me a different shape than expected.

my code is

```
def preprocess(img):
    img = np.array(img)
    resized = cv2.resize(img, (254, 254))
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(resized)/255
    img = np.array([img])
    
    return img
```

this is a pil image

> <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=L size=2144x1805 at
> 0x229615E2488>

And when I preprocess it, it gives this shape

```
the shape of the test image is  (1, 254, 254, 1)
```

and when I try the preprocess code outside of my project it works fine.

Comment: what are the dtypes of the arrays?

Comment: the dtype is float32

Comment: for both of them?

Comment: "image mode=L" means a grayscale image with one value (usually byte) per pixel.

Comment: yes both of them.

Comment: well there is nothing like image mode

Comment: base64Image = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/,"");                   this is image in front end which i recieve in the backend

Answer (score -1):

This means that your Network needs an image not in grayscale colors and you're unconsciously trimming that info. I suggest you to try `resized = cv2.resize(img, (254, 254, 3))` instead of `resized = cv2.resize(img, (254, 254))`. Because otherwise your telling to the resize method implicitly that you want an image on grayscale and you'll miss that last dimension.

Comment: this answer contains an actual error in the usage of `resize`. don't post answers if you neither know how those APIs need to be used nor bother to look the documentation up.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, I must admit there's been a while since I used opencv. @ChristophRackwitz please, help the guy for me.